# Win API - Unable to add pop up menu and icon to the window

Tags: winapi, menu, icons

I have found the following piece of code from http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/ to display menu and icon, but nothing happens. Only a simple window opens up , with no menu/icon. I have checked the code again and again but could not find the flaw (I am new to winAPI programming).I am using CodeBlocks Compiler. Here are the codes of the main file,resource file,and resource.h .

```
//menu_one.cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass";

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(Message)
    {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case ID_FILE_EXIT:
                    PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
                break;
                case ID_STUFF_GO:
                    MessageBox(hwnd, "You clicked Go!", "Woo!", MB_OK);
                break;
            }
        break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MYICON));
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MYMENU);
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm       = (HICON)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MYICON), IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, 0);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        g_szClassName,
        "A Menu",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 240, 120,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}

//resource.h
#define IDR_MYMENU                      101
#define IDI_MYICON                      201
#define ID_FILE_EXIT                    9001
#define ID_STUFF_GO                     9002

//menu_one.rc
#include "resource.h"
IDR_MYMENU MENU
BEGIN
    POPUP "&File"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "E&xit",ID_FILE_EXIT
    END
    POPUP "&Stuff"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "&Go",ID_STUFF_GO
        MENUITEM "Go &Somewhere Else",ID_STUFF_GOSOMEWHEREELSE,0,GRAYED
    END
END
IDI_MYICON ICON "menu_one.ico"
```

Comment: btw, there's no need for `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` here, you can use `hInstance`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation for this is that you are not passing the compiled resource file (.res) to the linker. Check the linker options in your project to make sure that the .res file is passed to the linker.

Comment: Thanks bro...What I did was File->New Project->Win 32 GUI (dialog) and copied the codes.. Code blocks handled the rest.